# upper bound for the ratio of two solutions of a Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ with integer coefficients. Define
$$
A=\{(m,n)\in (\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})^2: m-n=P(m)-P(n) \}
$$ and
$$
L=\max_{(m,n)\in A}\left|\frac{m}{n}\right|
$$
I can prove that $L$ is bounded by some constant depending on $P$. But I'm wondering if $L$ is bounded by some constant depending only on $d$, the degree of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. For example, let $d=2$. Consider the quadratic polynomial $P(x)=(x-1)(x-n)$. Then $P(m)=0$ has two solutions, who ratio goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity.